# Can a single vertex be rotated?

Tags: transforms, vertices, normals

In the duplication options for the dupli verts there is a option for `Rotation`. Witch brings me to my question, is there anyway to rotate a vertex? Vertex's have normals, is there any way to control which way the normal of a single unconnected vertex points?

Comment: Actually you can rotate vertex normals.
Blend4web addon is required for that. Here is full explanation:
https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/131/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Mesh_Structures#Normals).

- If the vertex pertains to one or more faces, its normal is the
  interpolated value of all the normals of these faces.
- If the vertex does not pertain to any face, its normal is aligned
  with the line from the object’s Origin passing through this vertex.

On a unconnected vertex the normal will always point away from the object's origin. On a vertex connected with one or more faces (like [stacker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10718/2217) said) Vertex normals are interpolated from face normals.

Answer (score 4):

Vertex normals are the interpolated face normals, you can easily check this by activating normal display.

[image]

and delete all vertices but one. It keeps the old interpolated value of the normal but no matter how you change the orientation the normal wouldn't change.

See also:

- [Wiki on Mesh Structures](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Mesh_Structures)