# Why are the normals of this primitive circle pointing upwards, and how to reset them?

Tags: scripting, normals

Using Blender 2.8, when creating a primitive circle using the API like this:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Euler
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=8, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0.03), rotation=Euler((0,0,0.3927)), radius=0.05)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()
```

It ends up with normals like this, pointing upwards a bit:
[image]

I noticed when **not** setting the location of the circle, like so, it does not happen.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Euler
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=8, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=Euler((0,0,0.3927)), radius=0.05)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()
```

I have failed thus far to understand why. In any case, I would like the normals to be pointing outwards, like so:

[image]

Is this possible? If yes, how? Thanks.

Comment: Vertices without face align their normals to the object's origin. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10700/can-a-single-vertex-be-rotated To fix them you could set the operator's `fill_type` parameter to either `TRIFAN` or `NGON` and then calculate each vertex normal manually.

Comment: At first sight this behaviour seems odd, to me..I wonder why a cross-product of the edges wouldn't make more sense....

Comment: A cross-product of the edges would be more intuitive indeed, at first sight. Don't know either if it has a particular reason to let them radiate from the origin.

Comment: @RobinBetts If the edges are inline then the cross product is (0, 0, 0).

Comment: The practical part of the issue was solved by not setting the location upon creating the prmitive circle, but afterwards with a new line of code.

Comment: @batFINGER There you go! That's why 'First Sights'  need to be  composted for a while.  (At least, mine do.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, in the absence of any faces from whose Face-Normals the Vertex-Normals can be derived, they resort to a spherical projection from the Object Origin.

[image]

Comment: Oops, hadn't noticed the dupe.