# How does Blender calculate vertex normals for a circle with no face?

Tags: normals

From what I heard, vertex normals are calculated by averaging the face normals of all the faces that share a particular vertex, perhaps by giving extra weightage to the normals from faces of large area

However, I noticed quite the peculiar case when I made Blender display vertex normals for a circle without any face:

[image]

Though there are no face normals to calculate the vertex normals from, Blender still displays vertex normals. The moment I give those verts a face, the normals change directions. How did Blender display vertex normals in the above pic if there are no faces to calculate the face normals from?

Comment: it looks like the normals of vertices without faces will point toward the opposite direction of the origin of the object, you'll see if you move your circle in Edit mode

Comment: @moonboots Very interesting, how exactly does it calculate distance to the origin? Alsoso, isthis behavior deliberately hardcoded or is this how vertex normals work in general?

Comment: mmh not sure what the distance has to do with your question. About your second question, vertex normal always take into account the face(s) it is part of, if it is part of a face, actually I never realized how it worked without face until now

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10727/2217

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The direction of the vertices' normals will depend on the face the vertices are part of:

[image]

If the vertices are not part of any face it looks like their normals will point towards the opposite direction of the object's origin:

[image]

Comment: How does it exactly evaluate a normal such that it points towards the origin at all times like in your gif file? As in, fundamentally what does it do to generate a normal that 'passes' through the origin? Is there a specific algorithm or formula for that?

Comment: I guess your question is too complicated for me, I hope someone will answer  ;)

Comment: nice animation!! +1

Comment: it's french cancan but with vertices

Comment: @Hash the formula is, object space vertex position, normalized.  Vector from one point to another point is P1 minus P2, and P2 here-- the origin-- is at 0,0,0.

Comment: @Nathan So if P2 = 0,0,0 then P1-P2 should be equal to p1 right? So does this mean the normal of the vertex = position vector of P1/ Magnitude of position vector p1?

Comment: @Hash Yes, except at the origin, where the vertex normal is 0.

Comment: @scurest why would the vertex normal be 0 at the origin? If a vertex was at the origin, with the circle's center somewhere close by, then by following p2-p1, wont the vertex normal be non 0?

Comment: @Hash When p1 is 0,0,0, the magnitude is zero, so you can't divide by it. In that case, the normal is defined to be zero. See eg. [this](https://developer.blender.org/rB61b22d27c8b9b64f04a7dd585eac11134184a235): "When the location is also zero, a zero normal warning should not be raised since this is the expected behavior of normal calculation".

Comment: @scurest Does this mean if I have a mesh where a vertice is at the origin, its normal would be 0 at that point? If lighting calculations involve vertex normals, then how would lighting be calculated at that vertex if the normal is 0 there?

Comment: @Nathan Also to come back to your comment, is the reason P1-P2 gives us a vector going from p1 to p2 that is also equal in length to the distance between p1 and p2  the same reason as to why with scalar numbers, X-Y gives us the 'size' of the of the number line going from y to x?

Comment: @Hash I dunno, that's a question for Math SE.  But realize that the length of P1-P2 *doesn't matter*, because normals are normal vectors.  Their length is always 1.  The actual normal is p1-p2/length(p1-p2).

Comment: @Nathan So the length doesnt matter, all we need is the right direction for the normal?

Answer (score 5):

> vertex normals are calculated by averaging the face normals of all the faces that share a particular vertex

While that's conceptually what's going on, it's not necessarily how it's implemented. It's actually kind of backwards. I can't speak to implementation details of Blender specifically, but in (polygon-based) computer graphics in general, the basic underlying building block is the vertex. Besides position, vertices can carry additional data, e.g., UV coordinates, a vertex color, a weight, and a normal vector. So the normals are associated with the vertices themselves.

Polygons are generally all built out of triangles (it's just that some edges may be hidden; e.g. a quad is two triangles with a hidden shared edge). So they are represented just as groups of 3 vertices. There isn't, like, a special "surface" primitive in the computer. It's just the 3 vertices that define the surface, and pretty much all other data can be derived or interpolated from the data carried by those vertices.  It's used to determine where the polygon is, if a ray intersects it or not, where the intersection point is on the surface, where to sample a texture to place a color somewhere on the surface, etc. And it's used to interpolate the normals and adjust shading accordingly.

If the normals all point in the same direction, then the polygon appears flat. For proper shading, these normals should be, well, normal to the surface; again, you can determine this direction from vertices, by using the cross-product operation.

If you have two polygons next to each other, and they are angled, the three vertex normals of one polygon will point in one direction, and those of the other polygon will point in a different direction, and you'll get that faceted look.

If you instead make the normals at the "connected" side match up, you get smooth shading. The usual way to do that is to find some kind of an average.

[image]

Note that with this approach, the vertices aren't truly shared, they just happen to be in the same place. There is also a way to create and render models where vertices along a common edge can truly be shared, but that doesn't affect this overall process.

Everything beyond that (things like n-gons, face normals, etc.) is likely an abstraction provided for you by Blender; a more user-friendly "facade" that lets you work in terms of concepts that are more natural, rather than with the raw underlying representation.

So, the circular shape you asked about is, under the hood, likely represented in a very similar way, except that now instead of polygons you just have edges, which are encoded as pair of vertices - and these vertices are the same underlying primitives used for full 3D, polygon-based models, and carry the same data (after all, you can extrude shapes, etc).

The problem is, to determine the direction of a normal, you need something to define a plane, and you need 3 non-collinear points to do that, but each edge has only 2, which is probably why they just make them point away from the objects pivot point (the [0,0,0] point in object's local coordinates), as [moonboots demonstrated](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229408/47567).

> How does it exactly evaluate a normal such that it points towards the origin at all times like in your gif file? As in, fundamentally what does it do to generate a normal that 'passes' through the origin? Is there a specific algorithm or formula for that? [Additional question by the OP, from a comment to another answer.]

Technically it points away from the origin (and away from the vertex). It's not very complicated; to get a vector directed from one point to another all you need to do is subtract the positions of the two points, i.e. [vertex] - [some other point]. You just subtract the individual components of the two vectors. This will give you a vector starting at [some other point] and ending at [vertex]. The order of operations is important; if you subtract them the other way around, the vector will point in the other direction.

You can then rescale the resulting vector as you see fit (this is just a mutiplication by a number), and sort of move it so that it starts at the vertex, for display purposes. Since in this case the other point is the origin, which is in local (object) space [0,0,0], you are subtracting the zero vector, which just gives you the original vertex position you started with - so you don't really need to calculate anything, you just take the position data from the vertex itself and rescale it, to make all normals be the same length.

When you have a proper face (or, rather, a triangle), then you can subtract the vertex positions in the same way to get two vectors that lie along two edges, and then use the cross product operation to produce a third vector that's perpendicular to both (and thus to the surface of the triangle).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. When you say "If you instead make the normals at the "connected" side match up, you get smooth shading. The usual way to do that is to find some kind of an average", is it not worthwhile to distinguish split normals from normals, as they are 2 different things?

Comment: Maybe disambiguate your last illustration :) .. if we're looking _down_ on **abc**, which is kind of what it feels like, with the normal sticking up like a flagpole.. then `Normal` is `Side2` x `Side1`, not `Side1` x `Side2`.

Comment: @Filip Milovanović I am confused by this paragraph specifically:

'to get a vector directed from one point to another all you need to do is subtract the positions of the two points, i.e. [vertex] - [some other point'

I tried using an online vector plotter to visualize it, but when I did that, the resultant vector does not result in a vector starting at some-other-point and ending at vertex?

Also in the last portion of your answer, why does subtracting vector positions of a polygon yield us vectors lying on the 2 edges exactly? Im struggling to understand the intuition

Comment: @Hash There's a mathematical detail I glossed over 'cause I thought it would complicate things; we think of vectors as having a starting point and an endpoint, but mathematically, a vector *only* has a magnitude and a direction (that is, it's only defined by the endpoint, and there's no starting point - *all* vectors are taken to start at [0, 0, 0], just arrows emanating form the origin). So when you do the subtraction you get a vector of the right length and orientation, but emanating from the origin. You can then sort of mentally move it to where you need it, keeping its orientation.

Comment: @Hash See for example this [demo](https://www.geogebra.org/m/vUAFWvmk) of how vector subtraction works; basically you negate (flip) one vector, and then you add that to the other; note that the resultant can be moved to the gap to exactly complete the triangle. Keep in mind that, in accordance to the mathematical definition mentioned previously, all this moving around is just a visual aid.

Comment: @Hash For your last question, imagine that the black point (in the demo) is the origin, and that the two vectors point to 2 vertices of a triangle (with the 3 one not depicted - let's say it's somewhere out of the page). The [x, y, z] components of each vector are then the position components of the corresponding vertex. So you see how you can get the edge when you do v-u. You do the same with the missing vertex (say w-u) to get the other edge; then you do the cross product of the two to obtain the normal, and then for display purposes, you visually move that normal where you need it shown.

Comment: @RobinBetts It's just something I grabbed online, but you're right, I'll see if I can find a better one.

Comment: @moonboots - "is it not worthwhile to distinguish split normals from normals" - but that's my point; it is worthwhile for us users, but all the way down under the hood, it makes no difference to the computer - in its internal representation, it's probably *all* split normals. When the normal is "not split", it just keeps all of them in sync, and shows them to you as one single normal, and if they are, it lets you manipulate them individually. (Again, I don't know specifically how Blender implements it, maybe they do something differently.)

Comment: @moonboots - This may be counter-intuitive, but while we, humans, like to categorize things, and make distinctions, computers often benefit when there's a way to find a common representation for apparently different things, because then they don't need to deal with special cases, but can treat everything in the same way, and this helps to make certain procedures simpler, and also create specialized massively parallel hardware (like the GPU).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović So does that mean v-u produces the missing vector WU. I am still struggling a bit to understand why subtracting 2 vectors of a polygon would give us those 2 vectors as you had stated in 'When you have a proper face (or, rather, a triangle), then you can subtract the vertex positions in the same way to get two vectors that lie along two edge'

Comment: @FilipMilovanović and as for the point you made regarding getting a vector directed from one point to another point, I understand the "one point" is the origin. As for the "another point", what is that another point exactly?

Comment: @Hash Does this help: https://paste.pics/D3JCE (open the image in full size, not sure if the text is legible otherwise). Regarding your question: so, it's just an "arrow" from the origin. The other point is at the tip of the arrow. This means that you can represent any point (e.g. any vertext) as an arrow from the origin to the vertex location (in fact, the triplet of [x, y, z] coordinates of a vertex *is* such a vector).

Comment: @Hash Now, if you draw an arrow between two arbitrary points in space, if you take the start of that arrow and place it at the origin (or anywhere else), it's considered to be the same vector. I.e., if you have two arrows and you can place them exactly on top of each other, to mathematicians, it's the same vector, they make no distinction. Its coordinate representation is whatever [x, y, z] the tip points to when the start is placed at the origin.